# Change the content of the admin bar in buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change the content of admin bar in the buddypress default template. It has options like My Account, Dashboard, Notifications. First, I want to delete the dashboard option. Next, I want to show different options for different user types in the 'my account' option. e.g. I have two user types- student and teacher. Now, I want a 'friends' option to show for the student, but not for the teacher, in the 'my account' section.

Comment: i wonder if i'll ever get an answer over here ?!?

Answer (score 0):

To delete Dashboard, try adding this to your functions.php or bp-custom.php:

```
remove_action( 'bp_adminbar_menus', 'bp_adminbar_thisblog_menu', 6);
```

You should be able to use this to conditionally remove/add menus. There's a relevant article here: http://codex.buddypress.org/theme-development/modifying-the-buddypress-admin-bar/